# Lambda expression Where by second column if first column is null. c#

Tags: c#

I have the example data.

```
Name      CreatedDate      UpdatedDate
---------------------------------------
Tony      10/10/2021       10/10/2022
David     NULL             10/10/2022
```

I just want to get data by `CreatedDate` field less than today, if `CreatedDate` field was null, I will get by `UpdatedDate` field.

```
var data = ...Where(x => x.CreatedDate.HasValue ? x.CreatedDate.Value : UpdatedDate < today)
```

Is that expression correct?

Hope everyone can help me.

Comment: How is the CreatedDate column defined. The 'HasValue ' only works for `System.Nullable` types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that CreatedDate is of type Date? (ie nullable so that HasValue works) so this slight tweak is needed, plus added parens for clarity

```
Where(x=> (x.CreatedDate.HasValue ? x.CreatedDate.Value : x.UpdatedDate) < today)
```

Always assuming 'today' has a valid date in it.

Comment: I would also suggest using `DateTime.Today` rather than assigning a variable of your own.

Comment: Thank you. I Applied  (x.CreatedDate ?? x.UpdatedDate) < today